# python how to print a previous input

Tags: python

```
def MainMenu ():
    print("Enter 1 to set values")
    print("enter 2 to display values")
    MainMenuInput = int(input("Enter:  "))
    if MainMenuInput == "1":
        setgen()
        MainMenu ()
    elif MainMenuInput == "2":
        print (fjuv)

def setgen ():
    fjuv = int(input("Amount of juveniles between 0 and 25?"))
    MainMenu ()

MainMenu ()
setgen ()
```

How to do make it so on `MainMenuInput == 2` it prints the values from `MainMenuInput == 1` which is the code in def `setgen?`

Comment: Please do a [MCVE]

Comment: @MosesKoledoye  done

Comment: Your indentations is screwed up. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

to do this you need/can define a Global Variable by putting `global` in the initializing part of your code that runs before the variables  are defined.

Comment: Sorry about the "confusing" wording

Comment: `global` is frowned upon. The best way would be to restructure the program and use parameters and return values.

Comment: Its the easiest way without to restructure the program, but I agree.

Comment: Variable in function can be accessed elsewhere if you do `functionname.variablename` as the variable then elsewhere you can do `thatfunctionnameyouwanttoaccessthevariablefrom.variablename`

Comment: True enough, I forgot